# how to find the pattern in a file where both pattern and file have differnt number of lines and space between words?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a variable that store a string.I am taking a worst case here

```
 var='this is 
    my 
          name'
```

how to find whether this variable is present in a file.txt or not

This is my file.txt

```
hi all
    this 
           is my 
              name
    but no one likes it
```

What i have tried

```
if grep -Fwq "$var" file.txt 
    then
    echo "Duplicate"
    fi
```

but this work only when both var and file.txt have common space and newline format

Comment: convert all white-space (space, tab, newline, etc) to single space for both variable and input file and then compare?

Comment: the file is big removing space is possible but removing all the newline is not possible

Comment: @j.doe What do you mean, why do you think removing whitespace is less expensive than removing newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***sed*** + ***grep*** approach:

```
echo "$var1"
this is 
    my 
          name
```

---

```
cat file.txt
hi all
    this 
           is my 
              name
    but no one likes it
```

---

Preparing the *pattern*:

```
p=$(sed -zE 's/[[:space:]]+/[[:space:]]*/g' <<< "$var1")
```

---

```
if grep -wzq "$p" file.txt; then echo "Duplicate"; fi
Duplicate
```

---

- `sed -zE 's/[[:space:]]+/[[:space:]]*/g'` - representing each space as POSIX character class for further using in `grep` command (multiple whitespaces were squeezed into single one)
- `-z` - Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline

Comment: This just matches `name`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Not sure why you only replied to me, but I have read the question, they want to match the entire string in `var`, this matches the single line `name`, remove `this 
           is my ` from the file and it will still match.

Comment: YMMV with assuming the input doesn't contain NUL characters. Their existence in text files is why `awk -v RS='\0'` is not considered a robust way to read a whole file at a time and `awk -v RS='^$'` is used instead (gawk only). You could do `sed 's/@/@A/g; s/\0/@B/g'` or similar on both the input file and the variable before running the grep to get around the problem.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest this was working great . but it fails if there is asterix (*) present in the var

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry but that was an example. Var and file both can have asterix.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS (and I'm also using `\s` instead of `[[:space:]]` for brevity since I'm using gawk anyway):

```
$ awk -v RS="$var" 'BEGIN{gsub(/\s+/,"\\s+",RS)} END{if (NR>1) print "Duplicate"}' file
Duplicate
```

The above will convert escape sequences in `var` to literal characters (e.g. `\t` -> a tab character, `\n` -> a newline character) before using RS, if that's undesirable then set RS using:

```
$ var="$var" awk 'BEGIN{RS=ENVIRON["var"]; ...
```

instead of setting it with `-v`.